# Creating a disc image on a Mac

Tags: mac, images, macbook, adobe-photoshop

My MacBook Pro is on the fritz! I bought a new iMac because I couldn't afford the new laptop. Is it possible for me to take a disc image of a MacBook Pro and have it all work on a new iMac with a newer OS? I really just want to keep Photoshop (yes, I did not buy it so I do not have the installers...)

Thanks for any info.

Comment: if you buy Photoshop you will not only get 'the installers' but you're also legally entitled to use it! :)

Answer (score 5):

Depending on how much your old MacBook is actually "on the fritz", you should be able to connect the two and use the migration assistant to move settings/files/apps from the old computer to the new one.

Here is the [Support Document](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3322) from Apple on how to use the migration assistant.

Comment: thank you...even apps huh?? great

Comment: I suspect Photoshop will be able to tell it's running on different hardware by querying the underlying serial numbers of the CPU, mobo, and hard drive..

Comment: Given that jonathan is already not entitled to be running it on his existing hardware, I doubt that he's going to care about not being entitled to run it on the new hardware.